# Vim makeprg make environment variable expansion

Tags: vim, makefile

This is bothering me more than it should and has me completely stumped. I feel like like finding the answer will have some good learning opportunities so hopefully it's relevant.

I do embedded C development with Vim and have a setup for hobbyist stuff with Arduino (using [Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile)). I use `:make` with some shortcuts with build projects.

An external define resolves the Arduino Makefile root directory in the project level Makefile: 'ARDMK_DIR=/usr/local/opt/arduino-mk'. This is define as an export in my shell (zsh). This is where it gets weird:

- Using `make` at the shell prompt the project builds fine:

```
make -d
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Reading makefile `/usr/local/opt/arduino-mk/Arduino.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
```

- However using `:make` in Vim the define becomes something from an old install:

```
:make
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Reading makefile `/usr/local/Cellar/arduino-mk/1.5.2/Arduino.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Makefile:24: /usr/local/Cellar/arduino-mk/1.5.2/Arduino.mk: No such file or directory
```

I cannot for the life of me find where ARDMK_DIR is being re-defined to '/usr/local/Cellar/arduino-mk/1.5.2'. Things I have tried:

- `setlocal makeprg=echo\ $ARDMK_DIR\ &&\ make\ -d\`: echo comes back with my shell define (/usr/local/opt/arduino-mk), but `make` fails with the error above!!
- `:echo $ARDMK_DIR`: again returns my shell define.
- `ag` my home directory for ARDMK_DIR, the only place it is defined is in my shell exports. Did since for my root directory to and same thing. Same thing for $VIMRUNTIME
- Even vim-disptach works fine calling the same `makeprg`?!
- Re-define `ARDMK_DIR` in the project Makefile. Everything builds find as expected. I don't want to do this however as I compile with different systems.
- The same vim config works on other macOS and Linux systems with expected behaviour.

Some where between `echo` and the actual execution of `make`, ARDMK_DIR is being re-defined. Why and can anyone think of a way of finding out where and solving this?

Comment: What is the output of `set shell?`.

Comment: shell=/usr/local/bin/zsh - as indicated by `echo` my env is being exported to the vim shell correctly.

Comment: That was it! There was an additional export of `ARDMK_DIR` in `.zshenv`. My `ag` search was missing the `--hidden` flag :facepalm: so didn't find it. Regardless, I didn't realise that `.zshenv` is read every new spawn - that explains why vim had my export in `.zshrc` but launching `make` sourced `.zshenv`, which overwrote it. Thanks!

Comment: I just deleted my comment, as I thought my testcase is wrong :-). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zsh has multiple init files that are sourced. The file `.zshenv` is always sourced, when the shell starts and the file `.zshrc` is only sourced when the shell is started in interactive mode.

If you define the variable `ARDMK_DIR` with different values in `.zshenv` and in `.zshrc`, the value from `.zshrc` will be used when you work interactive with the shell (entering commands, starting Vim, ...).

But when Vim starts a command it will start a non-interactive shell. In that case only the file `.zshenv` will be sourced, so you get the value from that file.

One question left:

Why did the following command first echo the correct value, but `make` uses the wrong?

```
:setlocal makeprg=echo\ $ARDMK_DIR\ &&\ make\ -d\
```

---

For testing, I started Vim under `strace`. Then :

```
:set makeprg=echo\ $EDITOR
:make
```

In the strace file I found the following line:

```
execve("/usr/bin/zsh", ["/usr/bin/zsh", "-c", "echo vi  2>&1| tee /tmp/vdxR5DH/"...], [/* 86 vars */]) = 0
```

As you can see, Vim executes `echo vi`, so it already expanded the environment variable `$EDITOR` to its value before calling the shell.

---

So the answer to the above question is, that the `echo` command echos the text, that Vim inserted into the command line while the `make` command gets the the variable value from the environment. As it is a non-interactive shell, it is the value from `.zshenv`.

Comment: Great breakdown and thanks for clarifying why `echo` had a different output to `make`. Some good lessons learnt.